# How to combine zip files that contain parts of shared subfolders?

Tags: ubuntu, google-drive-api, zip

I have downloaded a folder from google drive split into 4 zip files. This folder contains sub-folders which contain several files. The thing is the content of one sub-folder is split in different zip files. Is there a way to combine the zip files by merging back the contents of each sub-folder?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on OSX.
I used the Unarchiver https://theunarchiver.com/
Selected all my zip files and unzipped them.
For each files they asked me for a destination folder, I always gave the same folder.
Once the first one was finished, I got a popup saying the unzipping is done. It is important that you DO NOT click on that popup. Just let your computer be until all the files have been unzipped.
Let the magic happen, and happen it will :-)